# Spring boot MongoDB configuration

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working in a spring boot application & use both MySQL & mongodb as databases.Below you can see spring boot main application for MySQL.

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice"})
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice.domain"})
public class HuththaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HuththaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

if I use mongodb instead of mysql

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice.domain"})
```

should be change. How should be change?

Below you can see my entity class.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Document
public class EbankLog implements Serializable {

    private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String bothala;
    private String sapaththu;
    private String sereppu;
    private String kanda;
    private String bag;
}
```

Comment: Hello Saman, your question is not very clear. What problem are you having exactly? Any error messages that you could show us?

Comment: @gbandres Hello Saman, it we using mysql and hibernate there shoud be EntityScan   annotation,     if we use mongodb instead of hibernate(mysql) Entity scan shoud be change, How shoud it be change?

Comment: @gbandres +94713813992 is my whatsapp number,  if you call me, I can describe the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have not let Spring know where your MongoDb repositories are. In order to do that use `@EnableMongoRepositories`. See below codes:

```java
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "your.mongodb.repositories.package")
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice"})
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamal.nimalservice.domain"})
public class HuththaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HuththaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```